# Cannot load font true and no console access in Fedora

Tags: fedora, grub2

When I boot Fedora 17 this error appears:

```
Cannot open font file True
```

I found this question [Cannot open font file True](http://joyslearns.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/cannot-open-font-file-true-fedora-17/), but the person who faced the problem in that question can access the console.  In my case I can't access anything!

Can I use external live system like live Ubuntu to fix this problem? If "yes" what should I do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=799401), an update should fix it. Read through the comments at the cited bug, there you'll find the solution. And you can fix the problem using a LiveCD or the installation CD (select "rescue").